# How to put data in html with good format

Tags: html

Im working with Django and I have models information that I use in html

Problems I am having

```
<img src="{% static 'Bola/noticias_imagens/{{ noticia.noticia_imagem }}' %}"
```

How do I make this code work?

And again I have a text that has some tags like `<p>` and `<br>` and when I execute this code, it also shows the tags literally in the website
`{{ noticia.noticia_texto }}`
Example of text shown:

`"Hello.<p>Goodbye</p>"`

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First question:

```
{% with 'Bola/noticias_imagens/'|add:noticia.noticia_imagem as image_static %}
  <img src="{% static image_static %}">
{% endwith %}
```

Second question:

- You can do it with filter `{{ noticia.noticia_texto | safe }}`
- You can do it with tag `{% autoescape off %}{{ noticia.noticia_texto }}{% endautoescape %}`

But you must understand what are you doing, since this is not safe and could end up with HTML injection attacks.